# Leaflet draw: Keep limit editable objects, database consistency, make multi objects

Tags: database, draw, wiki, leaflet, feature-selection

Im planning to use Leaflet Draw as part of a special wiki with an embedded map. Users should be able to draw geo-objects that are related to one or more pages in the wiki. As the wiki-pages the objects are saved in a database and can be modified by every user. 
Problems:

1. How can i limit the number of editable objects to only one at a time?
2. How to keep the database consistent if two users are editing the same object at the same   time?
3. How can i generte multi-objects/combine several objects (e.g. polygons) to a super-object (multi-polygon)?
4. Does anybody know some similiar approches to my idea? 
   Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. You will have a single FeatureGroup for leaflet.draw's objects that can be edited. Simply figure out which objects will be edited and which won't be and add them to seperate FeatureGroups.
2. This can be handled in a few ways, maybe have a look around at general database consistency for this.
3. I'm not sure what you mean, maybe have a look at Well Known Text it might help you with storage here.

Comment: Thanks for your response gibbocool! The idea to add the object to edit to a seperate featuregroup is good.